# What are the best computer specifications for a flash presentation to be run off of?

Tags: flash, video, graphics, specifications, processor

I am creating a flash presentation that will be packaged up into .app or .exe and then run off of a projector. What are the best computer specifications to run the presentation smoothly? 
I'm thinking the processor and the video card has a lot to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash requirements are listed here on Adobe's site:

http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/tech-specs.html

If your PC meets or exceeds those requirements, you'll be all set.